# PHP И Excel не получается вывести все значения

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

Нужно сделать так, чтобы отмеченные строки выводилась в exsel в столбик (например, 5 отмеченные в столбик – это должно отобразится в exsel), но у меня чисто одна строка выводится в exsel, а остальные не выводится. Ниже код

```
<?php

public function Exsel($order_id)
{
    $order_query = $this->db->query("SELECT *, "
            . "(SELECT CONCAT(c.firstname, ' ', c.lastname) "
            . "FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "customer c WHERE c.customer_id = o.customer_id) AS customer "
            . "FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o WHERE o.order_id = '" . (int) $order_id . "'");
    $postavchik_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "postavchik ");

    if ($order_query->num_rows)
    {
        $reward = 0;

        $arr_postavchik = array('name' => $postavchik_query->row['name'], 'brend' => $postavchik_query->row['brend']);
        $array = array('telephone' => $order_query->row['telephone'],);

        require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/admin/exsel/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
        require_once ( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/admin/exsel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5.php');
// Создаем объект класса PHPExcel
        $xls = new PHPExcel();
// Устанавливаем индекс активного листа
        $xls->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
// Получаем активный лист
        $sheet = $xls->getActiveSheet();
// Подписываем лист
        $sheet->setTitle('Заявка');
        foreach($orders as $order)
        {
// Вставляем текст в ячейку A1
//for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
            $sheet->setCellValue("F7", $order_query->row['firstname']);
//}
        }


// Выводим HTTP-заголовки
        header("Expires: Mon, 1 Apr 1974 05:00:00 GMT");
        header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D,d M YH:i:s") . " GMT");
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
        header("Pragma: no-cache");
        header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=matrix.xls");

// Выводим содержимое файла
        $objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5($xls);
        $objWriter->save('php://output');
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

вот а вот еще код
public function Exsel()
{
    $this->load->language('sale/order');

    $this->data['title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

    if (isset($this->request->server['HTTPS']) && (($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == 'on') || ($this->request->server['HTTPS'] == '1')))
    {
        $this->data['base'] = HTTPS_SERVER;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->data['base'] = HTTP_SERVER;
    }
    $this->load->model('sale/order');
    $this->load->model('setting/setting');
    $this->data['orders'] = array();

    $orders = array();

    if (isset($this->request->post['selected']))
    {
        $orders = $this->request->post['selected'];
    }
    elseif (isset($this->request->get['order_id']))
    {
        $orders[] = $this->request->get['order_id'];
    }

    foreach($orders as $order_id)
    {
        $order_info = $this->model_sale_order->Exsel($order_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: больше информации. разбейте и объясните код. какая реакция на него. что именно получается\не получается. штатные телепаты в отпуске

Comment: Не получается вывести значения в столбик

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: допустим  меня есть число в массиве 11,22,33 и так далле.Мне нужно их в экселе воспроизвести в столбик а у меня только 11 выводит

Comment: while($row=$order_query->fetch_assoc()){
       //foreach($order_query->rows as $row){
          $aSheet->setCellValue("A".$i,$row['telephone']);
    $aSheet->setCellValue("B".$i,$row['lastname']);
    $i++;
        }

Comment: я думаю как то так